# Formatting title and clauses in isov2 document class

Tags: fonts, formatting, iso

I am currently working with the **isov2** document class.  I have been successful in changing the font of the entire document to Times New Roman.  However, I would like for the title, table of contents (the actual words 'Contents'), and all clauses to be in a different font.  I *think* the font is Arial, as seen in the image below.

I have also noticed that a period is being added to all clauses (clause, sclause and ssclause).  I would like for a period to ONLY be added to the clause.  I am unsure exactly how to edit my current code to adjust that as well.  My code follows the image below.  Thank you.

[image: Desired Font]

```
\documentclass[draft,wd,letterpaper]{isov2}
\let\ifpdf\relax 

% Overall font to Times New Roman
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% Add a period (.) after the clause numbering (in the actual document, NOT toc)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\standard{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201}
\yearofedition{2013}
\languageofedition{(E)}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}     % ToC includes ssclauses and above

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Document}{}{}

\tableofcontents

\clause{Clause} This is the first clause
\sclause{SClause} This is a subclause (sclause)
\ssclause{SSClause} This is a sub-subclause (ssclause)
\clause{Clause} This is the second clause
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font used for the clause titles is defined in `\Cfont`, `\SCfont` and `\SSCfont`; the standard definition is found in `iso11.clo` and it's sufficient to redefine them by adding `\sffamily`.

The period for `\clause` only can be obtained with a slick trick:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\csname dot#1\endcsname\quad
}
\newcommand{\dotclause}{.}
\makeatother
```

We define only `\dotclause`, so when `\sclause` or `\ssclause` is used, the `\csname...\endcsname` construct will just do `\relax`.

```
\documentclass[draft,wd,letterpaper]{isov2}

% Overall font to Times New Roman
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} % or Arial?

\renewcommand{\Cfont}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\SCfont}{\sffamily\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\SSCfont}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}


% Add a period (.) after the clause numbering (in the actual document, NOT toc)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\csname dot#1\endcsname\quad
}
\newcommand{\dotclause}{.}
\makeatother

\standard{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201}
\yearofedition{2013}
\languageofedition{(E)}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}     % ToC includes ssclauses and above

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Document}{}{}

\tableofcontents

\clause{Clause} This is the first clause
\sclause{SClause} This is a subclause (sclause)
\ssclause{SSClause} This is a sub-subclause (ssclause)
\clause{Clause} This is the second clause
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Slick, indeed. But I would like to understand... So `\dotsclause` etc. get treated as `\relax` rather than triggering complaints about undefined commands? Is that a feature of `\csname... \endcsname`?

Comment: @cfr Yes; if the control sequence resulting from `\csname...\endcsname` is not yet defined, it is (locally) defined as equivalent to `\relax` and used as such.

Comment: Thanks. That was my guess but guesses are often wrong when they are mine ;).